# why there is some blank image after downloading using Glide library?

Tags: android, android-glide

here is the screen recording of my app: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fBxcp5oU6AeAFW6M68ARA6toYv3sh7MQ/view?usp=sharing

after downloading the image paths from the server, I want to display some images using View Pager to create an Image Slideshow

as you can see from the video, the first 2 images can be displayed without problem, but the third and the forth image, it will show blank (just white, no image) for a while before eventually display the correct image

this is not the first launch of the app, after I reopen the app, this will happen again. not cached ?

why this is happened? as far as I know, Glide library will cache the image by default. so I expect I will not redownload the image

here is my Pager Adapter class:

```
class ImageSlideShowAdapter(val context: Context, val banners: List<Banner>) : PagerAdapter() {


    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, o: Any): Boolean {
        return view === o
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return banners.size
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {

        val imageView = ImageView(context)
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)

        Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(banners.get(position).getFormattedImageURL())
            .into(imageView)

        container.addView(imageView)

        return imageView


    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        container.removeView(`object` as View)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not caching the Images

in app level `build.gradle` add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` on top

in dependencies

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'   // for Kotlin
```

Add this class

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule

@GlideModule
class MyAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule()
```

Rebuild the project it will generate `GlideApp`

use `diskCacheStrategy` to cache image

```
  GlideApp.with(context)
    .load(banners.get(position).getFormattedImageURL())
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
    .into(imageView)
```

Comment: I somehow can't add diskCacheStartegy() method like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgMPF.png

Comment: You have to use   `GlideApp.with(context)` not `Glide.with(context)`

Comment: unfortunately the problem is still there after trying your method :(

Comment: It should not be,  the images will be cached , you can verify it by turning off internet .